# Is it recommended to travel to Patagonia in May?

Tags: winter, south-america, chile, patagonia

We're currently planning a South America trip and would love to go to Patagonia. But we're only starting in late April/early May and I'm afraid it's gonna be very cold already.

Currently, we think we would stay mainly on the Chilean side, but haven't really decided yet.

Primarily, we're interested in hiking and seeing and photographing the landscape. Of course with the right equipment, this is possible *everywhere*.

My concern is that there may be things like closed roads, out-of-service ferries, much higher prices or other things we'd have to watch out for. Or maybe the landscapes are just not so nice in winter, I don't know.

So is it still recommended to go there for a week or two? If so, is there anything specific we have to watch out for?

Also, how much does it depend on how far south we go?

Comment: What do you mean by *possible*? Since people live there, it's clearly possible to go there. There are winter sport resorts etc. What are you seeking to do?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the question based on your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Travel is certainly *possible*. [Punta Arenas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punta_Arenas) has 120,000 inhabitants and [Ushuaia](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ushuaia) on the Argentinian side has 60000 inhabitants (with [ski resorts apparently opening in June](http://www.patagonia-argentina.com/i/actividades/skiushuaia.php)). *Advisable* depends of course on what you want to do.

Wikipedia has useful information on climate:

[Puerto Montt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerto_Montt), at 41°28'S, has 6.0–12.7°C in May:

[image]

Much further south, [Punta Arenas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punta_Arenas) (53°10' S) has 1.0–6.4°C in May:

[image]

Cold is relative, but if you take appropriate clothing you should have no problems travelling in May.

Disclaimer: I have never been to Patagonia, all information is from the world wide web.